# How to get dropdown list items from pandas dataframe using python flask?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, dropdown

I need to add the data from the pandas dataframe to dropdown list in an html document using python flask...

```
@app.route('/api/v1/resources/getservices', methods=['GET'])
def api_services():
    return render_template('view.html',table=df.to_html())


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Dropdown</title>
     <h1>Services</h1>
</head>
<body>
<select name="table" method="GET" action="/">
  <option value="{{table[0]}}" selected>{{table[0]}}</option>
  {% for colour in table[1:] %}
  <option value="{{colour}}">{{colour}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am expecting is that the data from the column 'Service' in the pandas dataframe df should be added as items in the drop down list in the html file.. but whenever i am trying with the above code, drop down list is created without any items...

Comment: What was the debugging on the front end (e.g. F12 in Chrome)?

Comment: python flask and html

Answer (score 0):

when you call `to_html()` method, it will create the html table and you can't iterate over it. I don't know what was your df data, but i think this might work for you.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/api/v1/resources/getservices', methods=['GET'])
def api_services():
    d = {'Services': ["red", "green", "blue"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    return render_template('view.html', table=df)
```

**view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dropdown</title>
    <h1>Services</h1>
</head>
<body>
<select name="table" method="GET" action="/">
{% for colour in table["Services"] %}
        <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
</html>
```